# How to replace negative values in a dataframe column with a different value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataframe in R with close to one million rows and 91 columns. For one particular column, I need to replace all negative values with "the value + 360".

All 0 or positive values should remain unchanged.

There are many solutions for setting negative values to 0, or to NA, but I can't quite get this working.

Below are examples of my attempts, with dataframe called `df` and feature called `Bearing`.

```
df$Bearing = apply(df$Bearing, 2, function(x){x[x<0] = x[x+360]})

df$Bearing[df$Bearing <0] <- df%Bearing +360
```

What is the best way to achieve my aim?

Comment: You can try `ifelse`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df$Bearing[df$Bearing <0] <- df$Bearing[df$Bearing <0] +360
```

Comment: Thanks, Luke. I think there's a slight typo in your solution (% instead of $) but that's an elegant and simple solution that worked well for me, much appreciated.

Comment: Well spotted! Fixed above

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
df <- within(df, Bearing <- Bearing + ifelse(Bearing < 0, 360, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

If speed is an issue because of the size of your data.frame, consider using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, bearing := ifelse(bearing < 0, bearing + 360, bearing)]
```